# Is it possible to connect Xamarin ios App to swift watchOS Extension

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, watchos-2

I already have a WatchOSExtension developed under swift, is it possible to connect it to a newely developed xamarin ios project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use a Swift extension with a Xamarin app - this also applies to any form of iOS extension.

You will need to redo your extension with Xamarin. Documentation for watchOS can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/getting-started/

Answer (score 2):

I think the watch extension needs to be compiled into the the app bundle so I dont think this can be done (compile swift code into c#, i may be wrong). They also need references to each other see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/watch/getting-started/project-references/).

Its like saying "I have found some swift code can I just put this into my xamarin app and it will work?"